# Add a custom attribute to person class in opendj

Tags: custom-attributes, opendj

I follow http://opendj.forgerock.org/opendj-server/doc/admin-guide/index/chap-schema.html
to add a custom attribute to perosn class in opendj

1)create packt-services-user-blog  attribute
2)create packt-services-user-class class, and add packt-services-user-blog attribute
3)create custom-attr.ldif
dn: uid=user.0, ou=People,dc=example, dc=com
changetype: modify
add: objectClass
objectClass: person

add: packt-services-user-blog
packt-services-user-blog: Testing 1,2,3 ....
4)
./ldapmodify \
--port 389 \
--hostname www.openam.example.com \
--bindDN "cn=Directory Manager" \
--bindPassword opendj \
--filename custom-attr.ldif

But I get an error as follows:
Result:20
Message: can not modify entity uid=user.0,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com，Cause there are more than one reduplicated value in attribute objectClass : person

I guess this error results from I don't add attribute packt-services-user-blog to person successfully

So How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think the error message is quite explicit : Do not add ObjectClass: Person, because it creates duplicate values.

You need to add your custom objectClass: Packt-Services-User-Class and its attribute(s).

The packt-services-user-class needs to be defined as Auxiliary and then it can be added to any entry.

Regards,

Ludovic

Comment: Thanks,I should define packt-class as auxiliary. But after I update attribute in opendj, I can't create a new user. I get openam.idrepo.ldap.DJLDAPv3Repo exception number 65. I don't know why

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, just noticed this now. Error 65 means objectclass violation. Either you have an old version of OpenDJ and you are hitting a known limitation (restart will solve the problem), or you are trying to force AM to write something that is not compliant with the schema.